# My Application in Application manager can´t be uninstall. Why?

Tags: android, system, root

I have a system application, made by me, but to uninstall it, i can´t do it on the Applications manager. I have my phone rooted. So, why can't remove it ?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "system application"? And when you say you can't uninstall, do you mean the uninstall button is greyed out?

Comment: I have a button on my application, to install her to /system/priv-app, witch transform her to a system application. The problem, is that the i can´t uninstall her because the button just allow to "Deactivate", not to uninstall.

Comment: Can you disable the app's administrator access? http://www.phonearena.com/news/Cant-uninstall-an-Android-app-This-could-be-your-problem_id61301

Comment: The App don't show on the administrator access. Something missing on the manifest file ?  In the App´s manager, what show to me is the same that in point 2 of that link you pass to me, in the exemple of the app Drive.